# selenium web.direver error message "run time error -2146232576"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error like this when connecting to selenium. What could be the reason?

Thank you in advance for your support

[image]

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim baglan As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim url As String

url = "https://www.google.com"

baglan.Start "chrome"
baglan.Get url


End Sub
```